# iOs Push notifications, don't get alert asking for authorization

Tags: ios, apple-push-notifications

I hope you can help me troubleshoot my issue.
When I install my app, I don't get the message alert asking for the authorization to get push notifications.
I am thinking that if I don't get this message it's not my code to be wrong, but maybe it's a matter of certificates.
Am I right? How can I check if my provisioning file is correct?
I am using Xcode 5 and testing on ios7.0.2
I add a little more: I was never able to get the alert working

Comment: Try this General > Reset > Reset Location & Privacy.

Answer (score 2):

I had this issue when developing an app, it turned out I'd not set the entitlements up correctly. So make sure you have in your `AppDelegate`:

`[[UIApplication sharedApplication] registerForRemoteNotificationTypes:
     (UIRemoteNotificationTypeBadge | UIRemoteNotificationTypeSound | UIRemoteNotificationTypeAlert)];`

Make sure in `Developer Center` you've generated an AppID for your application as well, specifying that you want to use `Push Notifications`. Then you need to generate a `Provisioning Profile` to use for development/deployment with the device ID you want to install it on. Then you need to bring that `Provisioning Profile` into Xcode, and apply it to your project within the target `build settings`. That should bring up the `Push Notification` alert view to get the permission for the app to use push notifications. You then get the fun of setting up the SSL certificates but that's a whole other topic.

I found the [Ray Wenderlich Push Notification Tutorial](http://www.raywenderlich.com/32960/apple-push-notification-services-in-ios-6-tutorial-part-1) incredibly helpful when I went through it, I'd recommend following through if you're finding yourself stuck.

Edit; also keep in mind `Push Notifications` do not work on the `Simulator`, you must test them against an actual device as you won't see the alert view at all on the `Simulator`.

Comment: Being frankly I am using Phonegap/Cordova, I know there are issues on the Phonegap/Cordova side, but I am not sure I set everything properly from the certificate point of view. Please, tell me: 1) does the alert asking push authorization must appear no matter what the code is (it relys only on the provisioning file)? 2) is there a check I can make by on the provisioning file and/or XCode to see if my app is push enabled and the aps entitlements are correct?

Comment: As far as I'm aware you need the code for registering for remote notifications in your application at the delegate init point, and you need the correct provisioning file. I don't know if you can manually inspect the provisioning file to check the entitlements, but you have to set it up on the dev centre so you can verify it there.

Answer (score 1):

If you accept or decline it once this screen would not appear again. Go to setting and check permission for push notifications for your app.

> Settings->Notifications->YOUREAPP

Comment: Where are the settings you mention?

Comment: I don't find my app in the notification center

Comment: Ok show you addDelegate where you ask device token for push notifications.

Comment: But before investigating code... how can I investigate my certificates? If something is not right with them is it possible they don't make the alert appear? Does the alert depend on them?

Comment: This question is not connected with certificates

Answer (score 0):

In order to see the alertView:

1. uninstall the app
2. set the device date to at least 1 day after the current date
3. Reboot the device
4. Install and launch the app